# Exception when adding list to ObjectListView

Tags: c#, list, exception, .net-3.5, objectlistview

I just started with ObjectListView, and I am trying to replace the ListView I used before in my application. I managed to build a list using the following type I made:

```
public class Record
{
    public bool IsActive = true;

    public Record(string barcode, string info, string desc)
    {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.info = info;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    private string Barcode
    {
        get { return barcode; }
        set { barcode = value; }
    }

    private string barcode;

    private string Info
    {
        get { return info; }
        set { info = value; }
    }

    private string info;

    private string Desc
    {
        get { return desc; }
        set { desc = value; }
    }

    private string desc;
}
```

This seems to work so far and I managed to populate a list of this type with 830 entries.

When I try to fill the OLV with this list using `OLV.SetObjects(list)`, however, OLV freaks out and spams the following exception in the debug output, never ending:

> A first chance exception of type 'BrightIdeasSoftware.MungerException' occurred in ObjectListView.dll

I can't seem to retrieve more information on this exception, unfortunately, and google isn't really telling me anything either.

The columns I use in my OLV have the aspectnames "barcode", "info" and "desc". I hope this is the right way to use OLV, as I find the documentation rather confusing and have a hard time understanding it at all - the demo project isn't much help either.

**Why is this exception thrown, how can I prevent it and am I doing this OLV thing correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** The properties are set to private, and they should've been public. Once I switched that around, all was well.

Credit goes to drch on the C# chat for this amazing answer.

Comment: Hey I'm also using same library but I just can't get cells/column in edit mode can u help me on that. I'm using TreeListView.