# BrightIdeasSoftware MungerException

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I have two applications A and B which call the same dll (C), in this (C) I have a UC (E) which use another UC (D) as a Popup where is an objectlistview,

When i use E in A everything is ok. 
When I use E in B, when E call D I have a BrightIdeasSoftware.MungerException 
(see image below) it tells 'try to access to undefined method'

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see this to create a How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that we can help you better.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the callstack of your exception.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the Model objects you assign to the list i.e using `ListView.SetObjects()` doesn't implement a property or method that the column `AspectNames` are set too or that those properties/methods are declared private.

Makes sure the `AspectName` properties on your Object Listview columns match the properties on your objects and that those properties are declared public.

Comment: thanks but I've already checked that before to post my message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if all of the properties of your object are set to public?
See this link:
[Exception when adding list to ObjectListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107791/exception-when-adding-list-to-objectlistview)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers.

So Finally the problem is solved but i didn't know why and how? so this what happens :

First, before posting my question, I've all ready check that my properties are public and matches with the AspectNames Columns. 
Since I didn't understand the source of the problem, and I needed go forward, I've install the dotnetbar2 tool to replace the listbox of objectlistview.

Just after the install of the tool, my visual studio "passed away", no way to view codes, i've got just a black screen, i've become crazy, i didn't understand whats happen, so i decided to uninstal the devnotbar2 tool and use a classic list view of the MS framework. But what happens is strange my problem with the Objectlistview disappear, i've did change anything in my code but there's no more Munger Exception.

Anyone have an explication of what it happens? And how, the install and the uninstall of a tool could change something? 
And why my visual studio became crazy after the install of the dotnetbar?
 It's very useful tool, and I want to use it but i'm afraid that it make troubles again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure out which Property/Aspect is causing this is:

1. **Check ON** the Common Language Runtime Exceptions in the Exceptions Settings

[image]

2. Place two breakpoints here. MungerException happens at the second breakpoint. Pin `this.AspectName` variable, and see if it reaches the 2nd breakpoint or not.

[image]